# Getting database for Cassandra or building one from scratch?

Tags: cassandra

So, I'm new to Cassandra and I was wondering what the best approach would be to learn Cassandra.

Should I first focus on the design of a database and build one from scratch?
And as I was reading that Cassandra is great for writing. How can one observe that? Is there open source data that one can use? (I didn't really know where to look.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good point getting started with Cassandra are the free online courses from DataStax (an enterprise grade Cassandra distribution): https://academy.datastax.com/courses

And for Cassandra beeing good at writing data - have a look here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html

The write path comes down to these points:

- write the data into the commitlog (append only sequentially, no random io - therefore should be on its own disk to prevent head movements, with ssd no issue)
- write the data into memtables (kept in memory - very fast)

So in terms of disk, a write is a simple append to the commitlog in the first place. No data is directly written to the sstables (it's in the commitlog and memtable, which becomes flushed to disk at times as sstables), updates are not changing an sstable on disk (sstables are immutable, an update is written separately with a new timestamp), a delete does not remove data from sstables (sstables are immutable - instead a tombstone is written).

All updates and deletes produce new entries in memtable and sstables, to remove deleted data and to get rid of old versions of data from updates sstables on disk are compacted from time to time into a new one.

Also read about the different compaction strategies (can help you provide good performance), replication factor (how many copies of your data the cluster should keep) and consistency levels (how Cassandra should determine when a write or read is successful, hint: ALL is almost wrong all the time, look for QUORUM).